# Flipping tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

Currently, [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is a synonym for [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) - the latter is considered the main tag. However, the C++17 IS was published in July and, aside from some ISO formalities, is now effectively A Thing.

Is there a process for flipping which tag is the synonym and which is the main? Do all the [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) questions have to be retagged [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)?